# change display from field <input> into <table> in ajax codeignitier

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

Dear Expert need ur help

this my ajax

```
$.ajax({url : "<?php echo site_url('infokamar/ajax_pasien')?>/" + Kode,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {$('[name="norm"]').val(data.norm);
                $('[name="pasien"]').val(data.pasien);
                $('[name="alamat"]').val(data.alamat);
                $('[name="tanggal"]').val(data.tanggal);
                $('[name="jumlah"]').val(data.jumlah);
                $('#modal_form1').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
                $('.modal-title').text('LIHAT KAMAR'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title
```

but  i want to display under this table

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="6S0%"><thead><tr><th style="width:1px;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NO</FONT></th><th style="width:3px;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KODE</FONT></th><th style="width:3px;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RUANGAN</FONT></th><th style="width:3px;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KELAS</FONT></th>
<th style="width:3px;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KAMAR</FONT></th><th style="width:100px;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;JUMLAH TT</FONT></th><th style="width:100px;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SISA TT</FONT></th><th style="width:5px;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KONTROL</FONT></center> </th></tr>/thead><tbody></tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table>
```

need ur help

Comment: inside which tag what you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

using json encode and decode to set tabular formatted data and just set using selector tag

Answer (score 0):

im found the solution im using this in ajax thanks everyone

```
var tbaris = '<tr><td><center>'+data.norm+'</center></td>';
                tbaris += '<td>'+data.pasien+'</td>';
                tbaris += '<td>'+data.alamat+'</td>';
                tbaris += '<td><center>'+data.tanggal+'</center></td>';
                tbaris += '<td><center>'+data.jumlah+'</center></td>';

                tbaris += '<td><center>'+data.biaya+'</center></td></tr>';

            $('#table1 tbody').html(tbaris);
```